# Python replace nested dictionary in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'd like to replace a dictionary in a dictionary, but when I try I keep getting quotes and slashes around the added dictionary.

```
current_dict = {"header": {"from": "/app/off_grid_control/subscribe",
                               "messageId": "ef6b8e50620ac768569f1f7abc6507a5", "method": "SET",
                               "namespace": "Appliance.Control.ToggleX", "payloadVersion": 1,
                               "sign": "e48c24e510044d7e2d248c68ff2c10ca", "timestamp": 1601908439,
                               "triggerSrc": "Android"}, "payload": {"togglex": {"channel": 0, "onoff": 1}}}

raw_payload = {"togglex": {"channel": 0, "onoff": 1}}
payload = json.dumps(raw_payload)
```

From a print statement I get:

```
payload = {"togglex": {"channel": 0, "onoff": 0}}
```

So that looks fine.

Then I try and add the new dictionary part into the original dictionary:

```
current_dict["payload"] = payload
```

And get this:

```
current_dict = {"header": {"from": "/app/off_grid_control/subscribe",
                               "messageId": "ef6b8e50620ac768569f1f7abc6507a5", "method": "SET",
                               "namespace": "Appliance.Control.ToggleX", "payloadVersion": 1,
                               "sign": "e48c24e510044d7e2d248c68ff2c10ca", "timestamp": 1601908439,
                               "triggerSrc": "Android"}, "payload": "{\"togglex\": {\"channel\": 0, \"onoff\": 0}}"}
```

Noting all the added `"` and `\` around the payload values.
Can someone please help with out to add a different dictionary to "payload" cleanly?

Comment: Just remove the `json.dumps`. There is no need to encode the value at all

Comment: `current_dict["payload"] = raw_payload`? `raw_payload` is the dictionary. `payload` is the JSON dump which is a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do:

```
payload = json.dumps(raw_payload)
```

you're converting your dict to a json string that only looks like a dictionary.
if you want to add it to an outer dict as a python object, you need to to do it like this:

```
current_dict["payload"] = json.loads(payload)
```

Comment: Why? There is already `raw_payload`... It is not clear in the question why even `dump` at all

Comment: I suppose it might be needed as string somewhere else and also this clarification helps to understand as to why such a thing is happening.

Comment: It might be needed. It still seems weird to `load` what was just `dump`ed when you can just use the original data...

Comment: yeah, I agree, but I think mentioning both those issues helps to understand the problem more fully, not only to make it functional but also explain how this works. but you're right, the question does not imply that dumping is needed, so thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I ended up using dump in an effort to make the dictionary a string as it hadn't worked prior to doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I have no experience or knowledge of the json library, apart from the dumps option. I would never have known to look in json library for a solution. In hindsight it unfortuantely looks obvious. Thank you again for that.

Comment: One small carry on issue. When I do this:- payload = {"togglex": {"channel": 0, "onoff": 1}} , then this:- print("payload: {0}".format(payload)), it's changed my double quotes to single quotes: payload: {'togglex': {'channel': 0, 'onoff': 1}}, which causes the code to fail. Is there a way to stop the conversion?

Comment: if you print a python dict it will always show with single quotes, no matter what you used when defining it. If you want to print it with double quotes you need to convert it to json, like this:": print("payload: {0}".format(json.dumps(payload)))

Comment: @Markus, in your suggested edit, that had been rejected, you said: 
The solution is still giving me issues.

payload = {"togglex": {"channel": 0, "onoff": 0}}
current_dict["payload"] = json.loads(payload)

That's right, because now you're trying to load a python dict without previously dumping it to json. 
You have to do either (no dumping at all):
payload = {"togglex": {"channel": 0, "onoff": 0}}
current_dict["payload"] = payload 

or (dump and then load):

payload = json.dumps({"togglex": {"channel": 0, "onoff": 0}})
current_dict["payload"] = json.loads(payload)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I appreciate the help. It's unfortunate there are people who don't understand not everyone is focused and knowledgeable on single topics like them. So they have an immature no tolerance mentality. I hack code, have worked with Python, Java, C, C++ and Basic, I'm an Electronic Engineer, I rebuild engines, I’m an Avionics Technician, but I will never be a great coder and hence why I ask for help at places like this. I don't have the time and understanding to learn it well. Negative scoring just oozes naivety, arrogance and insecurity. We come here to learn not be berated.

Comment: Well, yeah, I think we've all been there at some point, glad I could help. Maybe since the issue had been cleared you could restore my answer as the accepted one?